# How to show "Switch user" option in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have Windows 10 Enterprise 1903 and I don't have any option to switch user. I manually have to execute `tsdiscon.exe` which is far from conveninant.

How to show the "Switch user" option in the start menu?

What is bizarre is that I do no have any `Switch User` option from any menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Click "Start".
2. Click upper icon (grey silhouette) in the left column.
3. The menu is opened, and its lower part shows all users available to switch to.

[image]

If this icon is not visible, then:

1. Open registry editor REGEDIT.EXE
2. Navigate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`.
3. Edit `HideFastUserSwitching` parameter and set its value to `0`.

Comment: Well, this is exactly my point. I don’t have this option visible :(

Comment: @nowox Possible solution added.

Comment: I have also added this `DWORD` key in the registry.

Comment: Did you restart the PC after registry mod?

Comment: Yes I restarted my computer after registering the key

Comment: In my case, HideFastUserSwitching was missing. Adding it manually did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is part of a domain, the domain administrator might have
disabled this option via GPO rule. You should in this case ask the
administrator to undo this setting.

For the non-domain case:

Microsoft has stashed this option away so the previous method described in the
other answer does not work anymore.

These methods still work (for the moment):

**Switch user via the Shut Down Windows dialog**

Open the Shut Down Windows dialog by
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
and select "Switch user" in the list and hit OK.

[image]

**Switch user via Ctrl+Alt+Del**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
and select "Switch user" in the options.

[image]

Both methods will bring you to the login screen to select the user to switch to.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have this option.

Comment: I verified and these options should exist in Windows 10 Enterprise 1903. Maybe something is wrong. Please do [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) to check system integrity.

Comment: Also, is your computer in a domain? Is your account admin? Is the account to switch to also admin?

Comment: If your computer is on a domain it is managed by someone else and they are responsible for making decisions about how your computer operates.